# Android, fast video processing

Tags: android, video, ffmpeg

I have troubles in my current project which requires video processing. Basically crop function (video should be squared), trimming (video shouldn't be longer than 30 seconds) and quality reduction (bitrate should be equal 713K).
I've succesfully embedded FFmpeg into application, all functions are working quite fine except one major detail - processing as per my boss is taking too long time. For video that have around 52 MB for 36 seconds it's taking 50 seconds to perforn all the operations (I'm trimming video to 30 seconds before any other operation obviously). The problem is that on parallel project on iOS video processing takes like 10-15 seconds for greater files. I assume that it's related to fact that they're using Apple QuickTime format which obviusly was developed by Apple so it's not surprising that it's working quite fast.
So well, it was introduction, now my question: is there any way for Android to process any video in any quality (for now we can assume that all videos are in h264) in time of 10-15 seconds (not more then in 30 seconds, as my boss said)? Some alternative to FFmpeg, that can perform operations faster? I'nm pretty sure that there is no possibility to perform such work in a such short time, since I already feel like I searched thought while Internet, but I want to make sure that there is really no possibility to do such work. If anyone can provide me links to solution more faster than FFmpeg or confirm that there is no such solution, I will be very gratefull.

**Update**
Thanks to Alex Cohn I've resolved this with MediaCodec. After a while, I got 20 seconds processing on 52MB video with cropping to square and lowering bitrate. For any future Googlers out of here I can suggest to take a look at this respository:
[Many stuff about MediaCodec](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/cts/+/jb-mr2-release/tests/tests/media/src/android/media/cts)
and more precisely at this file: [Extract, edit and encode again, video and audio](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/cts/+/jb-mr2-release/tests/tests/media/src/android/media/cts/ExtractDecodeEditEncodeMuxTest.java)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the video has been recorded on the same device, you have a very good chance that [MediaCodec](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodec.html) and native Android [media APIs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/package-summary.html) will be much faster (running both decoder and encoder in HW). Otherwise, you can *try* to decode the video with MediaCodec, and fall back to FFmpeg software decoder if it fails. Even then, if you can use MediaCodec for compression, this alone may deliver performance that will satisfy your boss.

There exists a (deprecated) project called libstagefright that builds FFmpeg with support for the hardware codec, and it was designed to work on API 10+.

Don't forget to compare the CPU characteristics of your Android device and the iOS platform (if that's a 6S, they have a significant fore). Consider multithreaded encoding and decoding.

*BTW:* Note that FFmpeg does not come with H264 encoder, and the typical bundle of FFmpeg+x264 is GPL, and requires all your app to be open sourced (or pay a hefty license fee for x264, but still be forced to comply with LGPL of FFmpeg).

Note that you can make square video by manipulating the MP4 headers only, without transcoding!

Comment: Hm, I already tryed to use HW on FFmpeg, but it failed. I also, obviously, read documentation of MediaCodec, but didn't get how to nicely integrate this. And there is problem since min API version for our project is 15, and MediaCodec irequires 16, but I think i can persuade team to bump minimal API to 16 if it will be necessary.  Anyway, I will get a closer look at MediaCodec and hopefully will find some solution with it :) What about h264, yes, we use libx264 and I've informed my boss about license problem. He said to don't bother abouth this, and left it with him, as I exactly did

Comment: HW support of FFmpeg means SIMD acceleration, i.e. modest incremental improvement. MediaCodec uses the HW encoder, which does is essentially limited by the memory bus.

Comment: API 15 is a strange limitation, with 2.2% devices today, and never being a popular platform. Either stick with Gingerbread, or shift to Jellybean or higher.

Comment: As I recall there is limitation for Android that our apps should coverage 98% of all devices. Althought, there are talks that we should bump this minimal API version to 16 for last half of an year :) Also, I;m not sure that I've understood your advice correctly, so just to make sure: did you mean that I basically should decode video with MC then pass frames to FFmpeg to process them and then encode video again or MC is able to handle all processing by itself? I don't see sufficient examples of processing anywhere so far.

Comment: Please use http://www.bigflake.com/mediacodec/ as a reference; some features of MediaCodec are only avaliable for API 18+, and the MediaMuxer resolves the container format problem. Still, it is not impossible to work with the native OpenMAX layer that enables the MediaCodec behind the scenes, and it is available for API 9+. But support back then was not very reliable, and different implementations required different shims to work around their inconsistencies.

Comment: To cover 98% of all active devices, you need to set minSDK as low as API 10.

Comment: No, I didn't explain myself clear enough: decode with either MC or FFmpeg, crop as desired (your own code), and then encode with MC.

Comment: I already using bugflake :) There is a lot of code, so I will need some time to dig into it deeper. Hopefully there will be all what I need. As I remeber Google statistics said that 15 min API give us desired 98%, but I can be wrong with it :) Thank you for clarification!

Comment: As of April 6, 2016 the Gingerbread devices account for 2.6%.